# Showing the structure of the program (menu) as a tree - does it a have name?

Tags: terminology, diagrams, engineering

In my thesis, I want to show the structure of the program, like this:

> ```
> > Menu  ---  Settings ---- Audio ---- ...
> >                     ---- Video
> > 
> >       ---  Perform  ---- Calculation
> >                     ---- Video demo
> ```

You know, like a map for a website, I would like to present a tree for the menu. But does this have a fancy name in SW engineering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen any specific term. I have seen all of the following used: *menu diagram*, *menu tree diagram*, *menu tree*.

Comment: Thanks, actually I think the menu tree sounds just fine :)